# Enable local-infile in Mysql on Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker container running mysql (current) which I started with

`docker run --name=mysql1 -d mysql/mysql-server`

I need to import some data but the default image doesn't enable local-infile.

I don't want to break the currently running db or take it down for long.

What are my options? Is it possible to apply the --local-infile switch to an already-running container?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[local_infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) is a global dynamic variable. To change at runtime execute the SQL:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile=1
```

The client side that connects need local_infile set on the connection. If using the mysql client there is a `--local-infile=1` option there, other wise look in the connection options if using a language/other script.

If you wanted to permanently enable this, the `local-infile=1` option should be in the a my.cnf file in the server under a server group like `[mysqld]`.

Comment: That's the one, thanks. Just got to get d6tstack to play ball now.

Comment: `?local_infile=1` needs to be part of the `create_engine` sqlalchemy URL like https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/407#issuecomment-169709114. Not sure why the db6stack doesn't show this in the examples.